# Magento 2 upload category using CSV

Tags: magento2, category

Is there any way we can create multiple categories at once and also create sub-categories in Magento 2?

Comment: Is there any module available that can help ?

Answer (score 0):

create fronted page and upload CSV to form.

PHTML File

```
<form class="categoryform" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("categoryimport/index/importcategory")?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" required class="required-entry" name="file_upload" />
    <button type="submit">Import</button>
    </form>
```

Controller file

```
<?php
namespace {{vendor}}\{{module}}\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
class Importcategory extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_category;
    protected $_repository;
    protected $csv;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csv,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $repository
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_category = $category;
        $this->_repository = $repository;
        $this->csv = $csv;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();
        if ($post)
        {
            if (isset($post['file_upload']['tmp_name']))
            {
                $arrResult = $this->csv->getData($post['file_upload']['tmp_name']);
                foreach ($arrResult as $key => $value)
                {
                    if ($key > 0)
                    {                
                        $parentid = 2;
                        if (is_string($value[1]))
                        {
                            $categoryTitle = $value[1]; // Category Name
                            $collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('name', ['in' => $categoryTitle]);
                            if ($collection->getSize())
                            {
                                $parentid = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (is_int(($value[1]))) 
                            $parentid = $value[1];
                        
                        $data = ['data' => ["parent_id" => $parentid, 'name' => $value[2], "is_active" => true, "position" => 10, "include_in_menu" => true, ]];
                        $checkCategory = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('name', ['in' => $value[2]])->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', ['in' => $parentid]);
                        if (!$checkCategory->getData())
                        {
                            $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create($data);
                            $result = $this->_repository->save($category);
                        }
                    }
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Category Imported Successfully');
                }
            }
        }
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

you csv would be like

```
S.No,Parent category ID/Name,Category
1,2,first
2,first,firstchild
3,first,secondchild
```

Reference Blog:
https://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-import-a-category-with-its-subcategories-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

It is default magento2 functionality to create a new category using import product CSV.